# WPF XAML - Design time and visibility of textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatrigger

I use Visual Studio 2019 with WPF / MVVM.

I have set a trigger to a textbox to control its visibiliy.
And during runtime this works well, the trigger checks the state of a radiobutton and sets the visibiliy of the textbox accoring to the radiobutton's state.

But during designtime this textbox is not visible.
How could I make this textbox to be visible during designtime ?

This is the XAML I have for the trigger:

```
<Style x:Key="text" TargetType="TextBox">

    <Style.Triggers>

       <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=Radiobutton1, Path=IsChecked}" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
        </DataTrigger>

        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=Radiobutton1, Path=IsChecked}" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </DataTrigger>

    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>


<TextBox Style="{StaticResource text}"  Text="test..... />
```

I found this article  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cacc5c30-8aa0-43c5-ad07-b063028653a2/designmode-and-visibility?forum=wpf  and did some tests using "DesignerProperties.IsInDesignMode" but I can not make this run,I get errors like "datatrigger can not be added to setterbasecollection".

Also I don't know if  "DesignerProperties.IsInDesignMode" is the right approach...

Comment: Make radiobutton1 ischecked true. Either by setting or using fallbackvalue on it's binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a workaround:

```
<Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=Radiobutton1, Path=IsChecked}" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=Radiobutton1, Path=IsChecked}" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Designtime}" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
        </DataTrigger>
```

then in Viewmodel:

```
public bool Designtime { get; set; }

public ViewModel()
{
    if (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(new DependencyObject()))
    {
        Designtime = true;
    }
}
```

And in the Window Tag

```
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type local:ViewModel},IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
```

Answer (score 6):

I think the answer is even simpler. By adding `d:Visibility="Visible"`, the textbox will be visible at design time.

```
<TextBox d:Visibility="Visible" Style="{StaticResource text}"  Text="test..... />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Blend namespace `IsHidden` attribute:

- add the Blend namespace if missing: `xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"`
- add the `d:IsHidden="True"` attribute on the element you want to hide at design time

Example:

```
<TextBox Style="{StaticResource text}"  Text="test....." d:IsHidden="True"/>
```

Comment: This is the reverse of what he wants. He wants it visible at design time